# Responsive design not working on heroku deployed rails app?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, responsive-design

I recently deployed a rails app onto: http://secret-brook-8909.herokuapp.com/

I intended it to look on the iphone 4s to look like it would using: http://responsive.victorcoulon.fr/

If you look at the stylesheet of my rails app you will actually see that i hardcoded all the widths of the containers to be 320px. But when I open it on my browser on my iphone it looks like its being opened on a larger resolution screen. Additionally, on the iPhone if you click the profile button, the button doesn't look the same as it does on a normal browser.

What can I do to fix these issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to add a viewport declaration on the head of the document

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Use this but same thing: 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any issues in the HTML code and when I shrink my browser it displays perfectly.

When testing with the iPhone be careful of the caching that Safari does. Make sure you clear the cache *and* also close down any running instances of Safari before trying again.